# Google maps loading infoWindows on Marker click

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Having trouble loading infoWindows with Google maps api.
The markers and infoWindowContent are json generated. All looks cool, the markers load in the map, even with special markers (see below).

Only the infoWindows are not loaded/opened from the 'var infoWindowContent'.

It is probably the 'addListener'-thing that I'm doing wrong for 2 days now. Any help is appreciated!

Here's all the code:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {lat:".$c_geo_latitude.", lng: ".$c_geo_longitude."}
    });

    setMarkers(map);
}
```

Then we have (everything in php):

```
var infoWindowContent = [$infoWindowItems];
```

Which contains fields like this (with pre-generated HTML):

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="InfoAll">'+
        '<h1>Hi you,</h1><div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<br />This marker is placed in the area where you are right now.</div></div>'],
    ['<div class="InfoAll">'+
    ....etc";
```

//Here the markers, plus the rest of the code.

```
var markers = [
    ['Place 1',52.066700,5.100000,1413,'hotel'],
    ['Place 2',52.095411,5.130759,1414,'parking'],
    ['Place 3',52.238407,5.470300,1415,'hotel'],
    ['Place 4',52.373610,4.885844,1416,'7Eleven']];

function setMarkers(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var marker = markers[i];

        if(marker[4] == \"hotel\") { showIcon = \"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png\"; setIndex = 1; }
        if(marker[4] == \"parking\") {  showIcon = \"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png\"; setIndex = 1; }
        if(marker[4] == \"7Eleven\") {  showIcon = \"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png\"; setIndex = 99; }

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: marker[1], lng: marker[2]},
        map: map,
        icon: showIcon,
        shape: shape,
        title: marker[0],
        zIndex: marker[3]
      });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            var currMarker = markers[i][3]; 
            $(document).data({ currMarker: currMarker }); 
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

ps. we need to keep this one, because we're loading data into the infoWindow as well:

```
$(document).data({ currMarker: currMarker });
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined`. If I fix that, the code works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q5rv12zr/1/)).  If your problem isn't just that "typo"/error, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, it looks like you solved it amazingly already. I have to learn the MCVE-protocol. Sorry for that. I'll try to get it running in our project, and after that I learn what you thought me! Wonder how I can credit you properly on this comment including the fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined.`  Because `infoWindow` isn't defined in the posted code.

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q5rv12zr/1/)

**code snippet which defines `infoWindow`:**

```js
var infoWindowContent = [
  ['<div class="InfoAll">' +
    '<h1>#1 Hi you,</h1><div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<br />This marker is placed in the area where you are right now.</div></div>'
  ],
  ['<div class="InfoAll">' +
    '<h1>#2 Hi you,</h1><div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<br />This marker is placed in the area where you are right now.</div></div>'
  ],
];
var markers = [
  ['Place 1', 52.066700, 5.100000, 1413, 'hotel'],
  ['Place 2', 52.095411, 5.130759, 1414, 'parking'],
  /* ['Place 3',52.238407,5.470300,1415,'hotel'],
  ['Place 4',52.373610,4.885844,1416,'7Eleven'] */
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script defer>
  var infoWindow;

  function initMap() {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {
        lat: 42,
        lng: -72
      }
    });
    setMarkers(map);
  }

  function setMarkers(map) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var marker = markers[i];

      if (marker[4] == "hotel") {
        showIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png";
        setIndex = 1;
      }
      if (marker[4] == "parking") {
        showIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png";
        setIndex = 1;
      }
      if (marker[4] == "7Eleven") {
        showIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png";
        setIndex = 99;
      }

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: marker[1],
          lng: marker[2]
        },
        map: map,
        icon: showIcon,
        title: marker[0],
        zIndex: marker[3]
      });
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          var currMarker = markers[i][3];
          $(document).data({
            currMarker: currMarker
          });
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```